# Synchronize with repository issue not able to compare with old code

Tags: eclipse, svn

The problem overview is shown in picture attached like each and every class is looking like newly created not getting the old code from SVN.I checked out an ANT project from SVN and had migrated to the maven after that in team-->synchronize with repository option I am not able to see the old code to compare with the changes that done. Every class looks like created new class no old code is getting to compare. Can any one help me out of these.

[After synchronizing with repository I am getting as follow when I tried to compare my code with the repository code I am not able to see any repository code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FcC8.png)

Thanks and Regards,
Sm.Aslam.

Comment: I added the eclipse tag as I think your are using eclipse, right? Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and add information which steps you took and what you tried to resolve the problem.

Comment: I had checked out code from svn and had done migration from ANT to MAVEN when I tried to do 
team-->synchronize with repository I am seeing all the project as new not able to compare with the old code.

Comment: Please post the output of `svn status` in your workspace.